# How do particles' varying reference frames average to a single macroscopic reference frame?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

Our center of mass remains approximately in a constant inertial reference frame (our accelerations combined with our meaningful time scales are negligible compared to c).  However, at the atomic and sub-atomic scale, particles jiggle and oscillate at what I understand to sometimes be relativistically non-negligible speeds and accelerations, sometimes having relative velocities among each other a non-negligible fraction of c.

My main question is: is there a formal or intuitive way to understand how all this nanoscopic reference frame switching sort of "averages out" all weird time dilation, length contraction, non-simultaneity, etc. effects to give rise to the effectively uniform inertial reference frame experienced by that macroscopic object?

Second question: does this mean that our subjectively perceived proper time is significantly different from the proper time experienced by the individual particles that make us up?  Would this have any important effect if any of those particles had comparably short lifetimes?  What is the relation between the proper time of the center of mass of an ensemble of high energy particles vs. the proper time of any given particle in the ensemble?

Comment: One interesting fact potentially relevant to your question. When two particles (or bodies) attract to each other (or repulse) electromagnetically (or gravitationally) and move with relativistic speeds, they attract in the direction of the instant current position. For example, the Moon rotates around the Earth while the Earth moves along its orbit around the Sun. We know that gravity moves with the speed of light, 1 second in this case. So does the Moon attract to the point where the Earth was 1 second ago? No, it is to where the Earth is right now. Even if they moved with relativistic speeds.

Comment: Whoa, that's fascinating, but also really counter-intuitive.  How does that not violate causality and faster-than-light communication?

Comment: Causality is preserved, as explained in the answers here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/how-fast-does-gravity-propagate and here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/338456/do-we-feel-a-gravitational-pull-towards-where-a-mass-will-be-in-the-future - Electromagnetism acts the same as gravity in this case, so this may potentially explain how multiple frames of moving particles instantly add up to one macroscopic frame.  Just a thought.